# SQLite "Error: Cannot find column 'studentID'"

Tags: sqlite

When I was trying to program a simple database to represent a elementary school, I came across this error when trying to compile the code.

The error occurs when I try to INSERT into the ATTENDS table.

I can't seem to find the error since everything else works properly. Also removing all the triggers still causes the error so they aren't the problem.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    name TEXT NOT NULL, 
    lastName TEXT NOT NULL, 
    gender TEXT COLLATE NOCASE NOT NULL ,
    DOB TEXT NOT NULL, 
    address TEXT NOT NULL, 
    grade TEXT NOT NULL,
    /* Checks */
    CHECK(gender IN ("m", "f", "o")),
    CHECK(grade IN("K", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Course(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    name TEXT NOT NULL, 
    grade TEXT COLLATE NOCASE NOT NULL,
    /* Checks */
    CHECK(grade IN("K", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Attends(
    studentID INTEGER,
    courseID INTEGER,
    gradePoints TEXT COLLATE NOCASE,
    FOREIGN KEY(studentID) REFERENCES Student(id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(courseID) REFERENCES Course(id), 
    /* Checks */
    CHECK(gradePoints ISNULL OR gradePoints IN ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")),
    UNIQUE(studentID, courseID)
);


CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS sameGrade 
BEFORE INSERT ON Attends 
WHEN (SELECT grade  FROM Student WHERE Student.id = studentID) <> (SELECT grade
FROM Course Where Course.id = courseID)
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT,'The student’s grade does not match the course’s grade.');
END;

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS changeGrade
BEFORE UPDATE ON Student
WHEN (NOT OLD.grade LIKE "K" AND NEW.grade LIKE "K") OR (NOT OLD.grade LIKE "K" AND NEW.grade < OLD.grade) 
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT,'The student cannot go into a lower grade.');
END;

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS max100Students
BEFORE INSERT ON Attends
WHEN 100 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Attends WHERE courseID = NEW.courseID)
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT,'Courses cannot have more than 100 students.');
END;


INSERT INTO Student(name,lastName,gender,DOB,address,grade) VALUES('Taylor','B','F','1992-04-25','123 1st ST','2');
INSERT INTO Student(name,lastName,gender,DOB,address,grade) VALUES('Taylor','B','F','1992-04-25','123 1st ST','2');
INSERT INTO Student(name,lastName,gender,DOB,address,grade) VALUES('Taylor','B','F','1992-04-25','123 1st ST','2');
INSERT INTO Student(name,lastName,gender,DOB,address,grade) VALUES('Taylor','B','F','1992-04-25','123 1st ST','2');
INSERT INTO Student(name,lastName,gender,DOB,address,grade) VALUES('Taylor','B','F','1992-04-25','123 1st ST','4');


INSERT INTO Course(name,grade) VALUES('Gym','K');
INSERT INTO Course(name,grade) VALUES('Gym','1');
INSERT INTO Course(name,grade) VALUES('Gym','2');
INSERT INTO Course(name,grade) VALUES('Gym','3');
INSERT INTO Course(name,grade) VALUES('Gym','4');
INSERT INTO Course(name,grade) VALUES('Gym','5');
INSERT INTO Course(name,grade) VALUES('Gym','6');

INSERT INTO Attends(studentID, courseID, gradePoints) VALUES(1,3,NULL);
INSERT INTO Attends(studentID, courseID, gradePoints) VALUES(2,3,NULL);
INSERT INTO Attends(studentID, courseID, gradePoints) VALUES(3,3,NULL);
-- INSERT INTO Attends(studentID, courseID, gradePoints) VALUES(4,3,NULL);
-- INSERT INTO Attends(studentID, courseID, gradePoints) VALUES(5,3,NULL);
```

Comment: your Student table have not StudentId Cloumn and have Id . It is rational error

Comment: I'm trying to add to the Attends table though which does have a StudentID column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the sameGrade trigger. You forgot to reference the row using NEW. Just prepend "NEW." to the "studentID" and "courseID" columns so that sqlite3 knows what you're referring to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS sameGrade 
BEFORE INSERT ON Attends 
WHEN (SELECT grade FROM Student WHERE Student.id = NEW.studentID) <> (SELECT grade FROM Course WHERE Course.id = NEW.courseID)
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT,'The student’s grade does not match the course’s grade.');
END;
```